# Android how to tell if sliding menu is visible

Tags: android, android-fragments, slidingmenu

I am using the [SlidingMenu](https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu) in my app and am trying to figure out how to tell when the menu is visible to the user.

I have an animation in my MainFragment that I want to stop when the menu is visible.

I've tried methods like:

```
            //In MainFragment

            //In my animation loop
            // ResponsiveUIActivity is where menu is Init
            ResponsiveUIActivity resp = (ResponsiveUIActivity) getActivity();
            SlidingMenu sm = resp.getSlidingMenu();

            if(sm.isFocused()){ //tried isActived(), isEnabled
                //cancel animation
            }
```

None of these seem to tell if me if the menu is visible. I'm having trouble distinguishing between the Menu Fragment and the MainFragment.

Comment: Not related to your issue, but I'd suggest ditching SlidingMenu and using the official DrawerLayout from Google:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/DrawerLayout.html

Comment: How far back is the api compatibility?

Comment: Not sure but it's probably at least to 2.2

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use

```
sm.isMenuShowing();
```

or if its secondary ,

```
sm.isSecondaryMenuShowing();
```

it will return true if it is. false if not.

Comment: Wow should of been able to find that, haha. Thanks.